# Hair mesh to hair particles

Tags: mesh, particles, hair

Is there a way to "convert" a hair mesh to hair particles? I have a few hair meshes and their textures are really low quality. So I would like to keep the hair shape and change it to particles, if it's possible somehow. Maybe by converting the parts of the hair mesh  to curves? But what if it's one solid part only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an addon called hairnet that can do this in some cases:
https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Objects/HairNet

This only works on mesh hair that has been modeled in certain ways though.